# Moving armature doesn't change transform data in Properties window

Tags: animation, armature, keyframes, properties

I'm trying to animate a tail wagging.  But sometimes (it seems randomly), the data in the Properties window doesn't change along with the movement of the armature.  The result is that when I try to set a keyframe, it has no effect.  The keyframe gets set to the original location of the armature rather than the new location.[image]

[image]

Comment: You're looking at the object info of entire armature, if you want to see the coordinates of bone change toggle the "N" panel in 3D view

Comment: Ohhhh... Thanks!  I'll try again.  I wonder why it sometimes worked this way?

Comment: Are you sure you were in pose mode and not in object mode? You should see the values you circled change only when the location of the origin changes

Comment: I think I was just confused.  Thanks for the help.